# How do I get an a tag and a p tag next to each other in html

Tags: html, css

I have this html:

```
<ol class="results-list">
    <% @results.sort_by { rand }.each do |result| %>
        <li class="<%= 'checked-out' if result.catalog_item.library_status == 'Checked out' %>">

            <div class="search-result">
                <%= link_to 'View', mobile_library_submission_checkout_path(result, search_term: params[:q], theme_id: @search_theme ? @search_theme.id : nil), method: :get, class: 'btn red view' %>
                <p class="title"><%= result.title %></p>

                <span class="meta">
                    <p class="display-name"><%= result.display_name %></p>
                    <% if result.theme %>
                        <p><%= result.theme.name %></p>
                    <% end %>
                    <p><%= result.location_string %></p>
                    <p class="tag-list"><%= result.tag_list.join(" / ") %></p>
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
    <% end %>
</ol>
```

How do I get the `link_to` and the p tag with `result.title` next to each other? I'm trying to use display-inline but to no avail...

```
.results-list {
    display: block;
    font-family: $reckless-medium;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 1em auto 0;
    counter-reset: item;
    list-style: none;

    .checked-out {
        color: $light-text;

        a {
            color: $light-text;

            .title { color: $light-text; }
        }

        .icon-caret-right-grey { background: none; }
    }

    .search-result {
      width: 40%;

      .view {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 2% 14% 2% 14%;
        margin-left: 1%;
        margin-right: 2%;
        color: $white;
      }

      a.view {
        display: inline-block
      }

      p.title {
        display: inline-block
      }
    }
```

It currently looks like this:

[image]

and

[image]

but I want the view button next to the bold title on the right. How do I do this? There should be enough room to fit the view button on the right.

Comment: What about flexbox?

Comment: could you post classes for btn, red, and other added to the button? It might be the content is too wide, so it wraps down.

Comment: `display: inline-block` should work if you set a width (or max-width) that allows them both to fit on one line ( < 50% of the container width)

Comment: @DBS I forgot to set width. IF you write the answer I'll give you credit! I need both displayinline and a workable width. Forgot to use the width.

Answer (score 0):

While `inline-block` elements can be shown on a single line, they will naturally grow to the size of their content, up to the boundaries of their container.

To force `inline-block` elements to display on a single line, you enforce a `max-width` that will allow both elements to appear on one line. (Bare in mind that setting both to 50% width can cause the elements to appear on a new line if there are any white-space characters between the elements e.g. `<div></div> <div></div>`)

```css
.container {
  display: block;
}

.a {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 45%;
  background-color: #800;
}

.b {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 45%;
  background-color: #080;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  <div class="b">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
```